# How to store a mysql value into a variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I would like to store the retrieve value from my mysql query into a variable so that i could insert the value into another table.

Below is the query to retrieve the value

```
connectionSelectPackageId.connect();

  let sqlSelectPackageId = "SELECT MAX(packageId) as maxId FROM recipients";

    connectionSelectPackageId.query(sqlSelectPackageId, function(err, rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {

      for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {

          console.log(rows[i].maxId);
  };
  };
});


    connectionSelectPackageId.end();
```

I know i am retrieving the value correctly, because when i console it out it prints out the correct number

```
      console.log(rows[i].maxId);
```

I would like the stored value to work pass the end of the connection (    `connectionSelectPackageId.end();`)

Thanks in advance

connectionInsert.connect();

```
 // Insert into the recipients the hashtag and information needed to opon the lock

function getDateTime() {
    var now     = new Date(); 
    var year    = now.getFullYear();
    var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
    var day     = now.getDate();
    var hour    = now.getHours();
    var minute  = now.getMinutes();
    var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
    if(month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0'+month;
    }
    if(day.toString().length == 1) {
        var day = '0'+day;
    }   
    if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0'+hour;
    }
    if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0'+minute;
    }
    if(second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0'+second;
    }   
    var dateTime = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
     return dateTime;
}

var dateTime = getDateTime();

  // Add email later on
  let sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO recipients (date, ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

   connectionInsert.query(sqlInsert, [dateTime, ..., ..., ...,...,..., ..., data], function(err, rows, fields) {
  });

connectionInsert.end();
```

the data is the value grabbed in the first query or `rows[i].maxId`

Comment: Why not just put it in a variable which his scope is broad enough for your needs (i.e global scope) ?! just 'var data=rows[i].maxId'

Comment: I tried but it seems like that variable only works within the scope of the query.

Comment: I replace console log with this var data=rows[i].maxId but when i do console log data outside of the scope of the query it says this variable is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Promise or callback function.

Is this the thing you want?

```
connectionSelectPackageId.connect();

var getSomeValues = function getSomeValues() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let sqlSelectPackageId = "SELECT MAX(packageId) as maxId FROM recipients";
        connectionSelectPackageId.query(sqlSelectPackageId, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(rows);
            };
        });
    });
}

getSomeValues().then(function(rows) {
    // do something with rows here

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

connectionSelectPackageId.end();
```

Comment: Thank you were getting there. I would want to use the value grabbed from the query into a subsequent query where i would insert this value into the database. I have updated my code with how the subsequent query would look like

Comment: So now you can use it as: ``

Comment: So now you can use the 2nd query inside `.then(function (rows) { })`